# Python how to convert string with special character into datetime

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, datetime-format, python-datetime

Trying to convert a string to datetime:

```
from datetime import datetime

date_string = "2021-07-07T02:27:00Z"

datetime.strptime('2021-07-07T02:27:00Z', '%Y-%M-%d %H:%M:%S')


Error:
error: redefinition of group name 'M' as group 5; was group 2 at position 107
```

Any then I tried:

```
datetime.fromisoformat(date_string)
```

Still not working.

Any friend can help?

Comment: %M is for minutes not for months (%m).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I parse an ISO 8601-formatted date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127803/how-do-i-parse-an-iso-8601-formatted-date)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your format string is incorrect.

---

```
>>> datetime.strptime(date_string, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')
datetime.datetime(2021, 7, 7, 2, 27, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

Comment: Z (= UTC) should not be ignored by using a literal Z in the parsing directive. Why? Because it gives you naive datetime, which Python treats as *local time*, which is most likely *not* UTC. You can use `%z` in the directive. See also the dupe question I linked.

Comment: @MrFuppes edited, thanks!